# How to skip join conditions on certain columns based on default values?

Tags: sql, hive, left-join, hql

I have a case where I have to left join TABLE1 with TABLE2 based on 8 columns --
*Segment_Hierarchy_Level_1_Name, Source_system, Segment_Code, Transaction_Sales_Type, Source_of_Customer, Multi_country_Deal, Customer_segment*

The issue is in TABLE 2 for some random rows these columns can have a default value as 'ALL' which means that I have to skip joining that column whenever value is 'ALL'.

I have a solution where I can create multiple instances of table 2 based on conditions where a column has value as 'ALL' but I would have to create a lot of instances in that case as my number of columns are 8.

I am looking for a simple solution for this problem in HIVE.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need only 1 join and for every column in `Table2` that may contain the value `'ALL'` the condition in the `ON` clause should be:

```
... AND (Table1.columnName = Table2.columnName OR Table2.columnName = 'ALL') AND ...
```

instead of just:

```
Table1.columnName = Table2.columnName
```

If Hive does not support `OR` in the `ON` clause, you can do it with a `CROSS JOIN` and a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Table1 CROSS JOIN Table2
WHERE (Table1.column1 = Table2.column1 OR Table2.column1 = 'ALL') 
   AND ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can *express* the join conditions as:

```
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on (t2.Segment_Hierarchy_Level_1_Name = t1.Segment_Hierarchy_Level_1_Name or
         t2.Segment_Hierarchy_Level_1_Name = 'ALL'
        ) and
        (t2.Source_system = t1.Source_system or
         t2.Source_system = 'ALL'
        ) and
        (t2.Segment_Code = t1.Segment_Code or
         t2.Segment_Code = 'ALL'
        ) and
        . . .   -- repeat for remaining columns
```

However, I suspect that the performance will be pretty bad.  You seem to have some columns that do not contain `'ALL'`.  You should leave those out and phrase the `JOIN` as:

```
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.Segment_Hierarchy_Level_1_Name = t1.Segment_Hierarchy_Level_1_Name and
        t2.Source_system = t1.Source_system and
        t2.RTM_Distribution_Channel = t1.RTM_Distribution_Channel and
        . . .  - non-wildcarded columns
        (t2.Segment_Code = t1.Segment_Code or
         t2.Segment_Code = 'ALL'
        ) and
        . . .   -- repeat for remaining wildcarded columns
```

The initial join conditions should help the performance a bit.

EDIT:

You can rephrase the last query using a `where` for the `OR` conditions:

```
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.Segment_Hierarchy_Level_1_Name = t1.Segment_Hierarchy_Level_1_Name and
        t2.Source_system = t1.Source_system and
        t2.RTM_Distribution_Channel = t1.RTM_Distribution_Channel and
        . . .  - non-wildcarded columns
where (t2.Segment_Code = t1.Segment_Code or
        t2.Segment_Code = 'ALL'
       ) and
        . . .   -- repeat for remaining wildcarded columns
```

That said, I thought the more recent versions of Hive did support `OR`.

Comment: Is there anything different or new in your answer that does not exist in my answer?